# How to run a "returns void" function with JSON parameter?

Tags: postgresql

This function created as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema._add1( vjson json, vtype smallint, vdate date) 
  returns void language 'plpgsql' cost 100 volatile security definer set search_path=myschema
as $$
begin
  insert into myschema.tbl(cjson, ctype, cdate)
  values(vjson, vtype, vdate);
end;
$$
```

Tbl definition:

```
create table myschema.tbl(cjson json, ctype smallint, cdate date)
```

Running the function

`select myschema._add1('{"j":["j1", "j2"]}', 1, '2021-02-26')` get

> ERROR: function myschema._add1hidoc(unknown, integer, unknown) does not
> exist  HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types.
> you might need to add explicit type casts.

`select myschema._add1('{"j":["j1", "j2"]}'::json, 1, '2021-02-26'::date)` get

> ERROR: function myschema._add1hidoc(json, integer, date) does not
> exist  HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types.
> you might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only parameter you did not cast explicitly was the `smallint` parameter, but I am sure, that's the problem. I tried [in the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=35dfb98ed6a90d8cc2758df3f2a9cf29) and it worked, after casting only the `int` to `smallint`:

```
select _add1('{"j":["j1", "j2"]}', 1::smallint, '2021-02-26')
```

Comment: Yeah, int to smallint is a downward must be resolved. Meanwhile the ERROR msg is very misleading. Thank you.